# how to get week and day total amount sql query

Tags: sql, laravel

this query only show month at my Laravel

```php
$personalSale = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT a.account_id, sum(c.purchase_amount) AS totAmount
        FROM dealer_infos a
        INNER JOIN user_infos b ON a.account_id = b.referrer_id
        INNER JOIN purchases c ON b.user_id = c.user_id
        WHERE  
        (
        month(str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) =  MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
        year(str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) =  year(CURDATE())
        )
        GROUP BY a.account_id 
        "));
```

Comment: this only show month at my laravel

Comment: What database is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently restrict it by month with:

```
month(str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) =  MONTH(CURDATE()) and
year(str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) =  year(CURDATE())
```

Here are the week total:

```
week(str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) =  week(CURDATE()) and
year(str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) =  year(CURDATE())
```

and day total:

```
str_to_date(c.purchase_date, '%d/%m/%Y') = CURDATE()
```